# Check if user,phone or email is already registered using java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, exception, try-catch

I create the first try/catch to check if user,email or phone number is already registered, but I got a `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set`, when I set a non registered name. When I send a registered name got `java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set`. What's happening?

```
    public void createUser(User user) throws NameFieldNotFilledException,EmailFieldNotFilledException, PhoneFieldNotFilledException,
    PasswordFieldNotFilledException, PasswordConfirmationDoesNotMatchException, EmailNotValidException, PasswordInvalidException, 
    UserAlreadyRegisteredException, EmailAlreadyRegisteredException, PhoneAlreadyRegisteredException{
        
        String userSalt = PBKDF2Salt.getSalt();
        Matcher matcherEmail = patternEmail.matcher(user.getEmail());
        Matcher matcherPassword = patternPassword.matcher(user.getPassword());
        
        
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.databaseMySQL.getConnection().
                    prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM OS_USERS WHERE USR_NAME = ? ;");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
            ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            if (resultSet.getString("USR_NAME").equals(user.getName())) 
                throw new UserAlreadyRegisteredException("User already registered");
            if (resultSet.getString("USR_EMAIL").equals(user.getEmail()))
                throw new EmailAlreadyRegisteredException("Email already registered");
            if (resultSet.getString("USR_PHONE").equals(user.getPhone())) 
                throw new PhoneAlreadyRegisteredException("Phone already registered");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        if (user.getName() == null || user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("") || user.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("\n")) 
            throw new NameFieldNotFilledException("Name is required");
        else if (user.getEmail() == null || user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("") || user.getEmail().equalsIgnoreCase("\n"))
            throw new EmailFieldNotFilledException("Email is required");
        else if (user.getPhone() == null || user.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase("") || user.getPhone().equalsIgnoreCase("\n"))
            throw new PhoneFieldNotFilledException("Phone is required");
        else if (user.getPassword() == null || user.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase("") || user.getPassword().equalsIgnoreCase("\n"))
            throw new PasswordFieldNotFilledException("Password is required");
        else if (! user.getConfirmPassword().equals(user.getPassword()))
            throw new PasswordConfirmationDoesNotMatchException("Password and confirm password do not match");
        else if (! matcherEmail.matches())
            throw new EmailNotValidException("Email format invalid. Example valid: user@domain.com");
        else if (! matcherPassword.matches())
            throw new PasswordInvalidException("Invalid password");
        else {
            try {
                PreparedStatement preparedStatement = this.databaseMySQL.getConnection().prepareStatement("INSERT INTO OS_USERS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);");
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, user.getId());
                preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getName());
                preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getEmail());
                preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getPhone());
                preparedStatement.setString(5, PBKDF2Salt.hashing(user.getPassword(),userSalt));
                preparedStatement.setString(6,userSalt);
                preparedStatement.execute();
            }catch(SQLException exception){
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to throw these exception if already exists username, email or phone in my database

Comment: You need to call `resultSet.next()`.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question, I would urge you to take a peek at [Java Bean Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation).

Comment: it was the result set, i did resultSet.next() && ..., I'll take a look at java bean validation, thank you guys

Comment: Add `if (resultSet.next()) { // your checking logic here }`